# Assign a value to a matrix cell with the new BusinessOne SDK

Tags: c#, matrix, sapb1

I have to migrate my add-on code from old UI/DI libraries to new BusineesOneSDK. And one problem I ran into was when assigning
values to a matrix cell. You can see my previous code below.

```
oMatrix.Columns.Item(20).Cells.Item(i + 1).Specific.Value = price[i]; //price is a double value
```

I can't use this line any more because there's no "specific.value" for a matrix cell in new SDK.
Then I tried the following line which also doesn't work.

```
oMatrix.Columns.Item(21).Cells.Item(i + 1) = (SAPbouiCOM.Cell)tempy;   //here tempy is also a double
```

I can't use "----.specific", because it's just a read-only value in new SDK. I posted the same question in SAP forum and hasn't got an answer too.

How can I simply assign a value to a matrix cell in new SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found an answer for this question. You have to cast the matrix cell to a SAPbouiCOM.EditText object and then you can assign a string value to that. What I did was I copied the double to a String and then assigned it to the cell.

```
 string temp = discount[i].ToString().Replace(',', '.');
((SAPbouiCOM.EditText)oMatrix.Columns.Item(20).Cells.Item(i + 1).Specific).Value = temp;
```